# memcpy'ing std::string in C++

Tags: c++, memcpy

For the Eigen matrix library, someone filed the following issue:

https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=74&t=140169

As I understand, the problem was that you cannot do a memcpy-based swap of two std::strings.

memcpy'ing here doesn't really seem advisable, but I also don't understand the problem the reporter is identifying.

It seems like if std::string is conceptually:

```
class string
{
    union
    {
        class heap_str_
        {
            char* str_;
            size_t len_;
        }
        char small_str[16];
    }

};
```

I think both of these would be okay under a memcpy (?) (ownership issues not withstanding, which I guess would be 'okay' with a swap).

What am I missing here?

Comment: You cannot memcpy non POD, especially one that has raw pointer.

Comment: If you `memcpy`, and the source goes out of scope, what happens to the pointer `str`?

Comment: @Slava pointers themselves are POD, and so is OP's data structure as presented. Obviously, ownership semantics are a consideration, but pointers themselves are absolutely fine to be memcpy'ed

Comment: @Frank maybe I made myself not clear - has raw pointer with dynamically allocated memory that this object has ownership. And data structure OP mentions definitely not complete as it is about `std::string`

Comment: It's almost certain that your `string` class would manage the buffer pointed to by `str_` and `delete` it or otherwise release it at the end of it's lifetime. By making a bitwise copy of your instance, you would have two objects that both assume to have ownership of that buffer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bug has the following detail in it:

> internal data was not invariant of the storage location (storing an offset into this).

Which immediately invalidates your assumptions.

The structure **probably** looks something along these general lines:

```
class string
{
    char* str_;
    union
    {
        size_t len_;
        char small_str[16];
    };
};
```

So that `str_` can be accessed without having to check for SSO on every single access.

Comment: I guess part of my confusion is, is std::string really not invariant of storage location?

Comment: Okay, light bulb goes on. Thanks.  A few other implementations around the web suggested implementing as I did, but it looks like yours is more common in practice. Indeed that would not fly with a _conceptual_ memcpy.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that SSO is unsafe to `memcpy` because the pointer to the data is usually redirected to the internal buffer inside the stack portion of the object. So when the object is copied to a new location, the pointer still points to the (old, possibly no longer valid) location inside the old object.

And of course, `std::string` (and all non-POD types) should generally not be `memcpy`'d in the first place, especially when heap allocation is involved, as it risks, at the very least, double-deletion or heap corruption.

So no, you should never, ever, ever, `memcpy` a non-POD. Even if you think you should/need to. Use `std::copy` or figure something else out.