# Read Access Violation from utility standard header after memcpy

Tags: c++, winapi, ipc

We have an existing program that pulls data from sensors and shares results with a PLC using shared memory - this is working fine. I'm developing another application to run on the same PC that will access the shared memory to display certain info on a UI, output logs etc. I have it to the point where it is correctly reading the shared memory and getting the current values, but for some reason after the function completes, I'm getting a read access violation (thrown from the utility header???).

When I step through with the debugger, I can see the getData() function getting the correct values, newData.name and newData.id_number are output correctly, but when the main() function ends, I get an exception (from the utility standard header):

Exception thrown: read access violation.
_Val was 0x1B093CC83D8.

Here is my code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <windows.h>


const int kBufSize = 4096;

struct Test_Data_Struct {
    std::string name;
    int id_number;
};

struct CommunicationParameters {
    HANDLE hMapFile;    //  handler
    LPCTSTR pBuf;   //  buffer
    int status; //  status of shared memory
};

CommunicationParameters CreateOrAccessSharedMemory(LPCTSTR lpName) {
    HANDLE hMapFile = NULL;
    LPCTSTR pBuf;

    hMapFile = OpenFileMapping(
        FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS,   // read/write access
        FALSE,                 // do not inherit the name
        lpName);               // name of mapping object

    //  if not exist
    if (hMapFile == NULL)
    {
        hMapFile = CreateFileMapping(
            INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE,    // use paging file
            NULL,                    // default security
            PAGE_READWRITE,          // read/write access
            0,                       // maximum object size (high-order DWORD)
            kBufSize,                // maximum object size (low-order DWORD)
            lpName);                 // name of mapping object
    }

    //  check whether shared memory is created successfully
    if (hMapFile == NULL)
    {
        _tprintf(TEXT("Could not create file mapping object (%d).\n"),
            GetLastError());
    }

    pBuf = (LPTSTR)MapViewOfFile(hMapFile, // handle to map object
        FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, // read/write permission
        0,
        0,
        kBufSize);

    if (pBuf == NULL)
    {
        _tprintf(TEXT("Could not map view of file (%d).\n"),
            GetLastError());

        CloseHandle(hMapFile);
    }

    CommunicationParameters shared_memory;
    if (pBuf != NULL || hMapFile != NULL) {
        shared_memory.hMapFile = hMapFile;
        shared_memory.pBuf = pBuf;
        shared_memory.status = 1;
    }
    else {
        shared_memory.status = 0;
    }

    return shared_memory;
}

Test_Data_Struct getData()
{
    LPCTSTR test_data_kernel_location = L"Global\\Test_Object_1";
    CommunicationParameters test_data_kernel_object = CreateOrAccessSharedMemory(test_data_kernel_location);

    Test_Data_Struct incoming_data;
    memcpy(&incoming_data, test_data_kernel_object.pBuf, sizeof(incoming_data));
    

    // Unmap view of file and close file mapping object handles
    UnmapViewOfFile(test_data_kernel_object.pBuf);
    CloseHandle(test_data_kernel_object.hMapFile);

    return incoming_data;
}


int main() {
    Test_Data_Struct newData = getData();
    std::cout << newData.name << " " << newData.id_number;

}
```

If I comment out the memcpy function in getData() and just return an integer or whatever I do not get the exception. I've tried using CopyMemory() as well, makes no difference.

I also have another program working that copies out the shared memory and prints the data to console every 1 second on a a loop. That works fine, it seems to be a problem after the function ends, not during it.

Comment: `struct Test_Data_Struct { std::string name; int id_number;};` -- Due to the `std::string` member, this `struct` is not trivially-copyable, thus cannot be used for `memcpy` usage.

Comment: `memcpy` is a very simple copy of bits and bytes that assigns no meaning to the data copied. `std::string` is, at it's simplest, a pointer to an array and some book-keeping tracing the capacity of the array and length of the string in it. `memcpy` will reproduce the `std::string` exactly, so now you have two `std::strings` pointing to the same array. As soon as one of the `std::string`s changes that array, the other `std::string` is broken.

Comment: This is most visible when one `string` frees the buffer when the `string` is destroyed or to allocate a larger buffer. The broken `string` is left holding a pointer to invalid memory and becomes a timebomb.

Comment: Undefined behaviour due to `memcpy` on a `std::string`. But the whole concept of storing a `std::string` in binary form in a file is broken. A `std::string` potentially contains a pointer to allocated memory. You cannot straightforwardly share that pointer between different processes.

Comment: Use [`std::copy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) instead of `memcpy` because `std::copy` correctly interprets the object being copied and calls the correct copying functions.

Comment: Also, a string manages dynamic allocated memory. Copying a pointer from a different process into it, will result in UB as soon the std::string tries to delete it. You may only delete memory created with your own binary.

Comment: [See this](https://godbolt.org/z/oPve6Ehj1).  Also, trivially-copyable types that contains pointer members are also excluded from being used in this way by `malloc`.  Second, to show why your code could never work, look at the `sizeof` information.  Assume the `name` really contained 1000 characters.  Look at your call to `memcpy`, and in particular, the last parameter.  How is `40` going to turn into 1000 or more characters to read?  It can't.  Thus your idea could never work.

Comment: Don't know what duplicate link to give, but this is clearly an issue with attempting to blast bits into a non-trivially-copyable object using `memcpy` or similar, and ripping the object to shreds by doing so.

Comment: *I also have another program working that copies out the shared memory and prints the data to console every 1 second on a a loop* -- If the other program does what the code that you're showing does, then that other program is also broken, its just that it hasn't broken down (yet).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [memcpy'ing std::string in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50377059/memcpying-stdstring-in-c)

Comment: Regardless of *how* a `std::string` gets copied, you simply can't *share* a `std::string` object across process boundaries, period. You need to change the shared memory to hold a `char[]` array instead.  On a side note: since the mapping has a name assigned, there is no need to call `OpenFileMapping()`, you can just call `CreateFileMapping()` by itself instead. If the mapping already exists then `CreateFileMapping()` will return a `HANDLE` to it, and `GetLastError()` will return `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue can be reproduced with just a few lines of code:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    unsigned char const buffer[sizeof(std::string)] = {0};
    std::string str;

    std::memcpy(&str, &buffer[0], sizeof(str));

    std::cout << str << "\n";
}
```

This code exhibits undefined behavior (UB) in failing to comply with the requirements for [`std::memcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy), specifically, the objects pointed to must be [*`TriviallyCopyable`*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/TriviallyCopyable). While `buffer` is, `str` in the repro here [is not](https://godbolt.org/z/xdGK95rrr).

The solution is to either

- exclusively use types that are *`TriviallyCopyable`*
- or use a more advanced deserializer, that knows how to construct objects that aren't *`TriviallyCopyable`* from a sequence of bytes in memory.